# knit2pdf in R shiny: how to export renderText

Tags: r, shiny, latex, knitr

I am new to Shiny and it really gives me headaches this problem. I have made a Shiny app where you upload an excel, set some variables and then makes some statistical test on that variables( first a regression model then model assumption). I need to export a pdf file which contains the outputs of the regression model and the statistical test along with the conclusions of the tests.

I am using knit2pdf and this is my code:
Server:

```
testey=reactive({
   
   y=df_sel()[[print(input$y)]]
    
   if(input$primavar==1){
      
      probaty=adf.test(y)}
    
    else {
      if(input$primavar==2){
        
        probaty=pp.test(y)
      }
      else {
        probaty=kpss.test(y, null="Trend")
      }}
    probaty
  })

output$Conclusiony <- renderText({
    
    if(input$primavar==1 | input$primavar==2){
      if(testey()$p.value < 0.05){mensaje="We reject the null hypothesis, the variable is stationary"}else{mensaje="We keep the null hypothesis, the variable is not stationary"}
      mensaje}
    else {
      if(testey()$p.value > 0.05){mensaje="We accept the null hypothesis, the variable is stationary"}else{mensaje="We reject the null hypothesis, the  variable is not stationary"}
      mensaje}
    
    
  })
output$report = downloadHandler(
     filename = 'myreport.pdf',
  
     content = function(file) {
       out = knit2pdf('input.Rnw', clean = TRUE)
       file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
   },
   
     contentType = 'application/pdf'
   )
```

input.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


<<Data>>=


# write.table(datos(),
#                   row.names = FALSE)
@

<<Stationarity>>=
print(testey())
print(Conclusiony())

@


<<Model>>=
print(Reg.model)
print(Reg.fit)
@




\end{document}
```

The reactive function `testey` is displayed in the pdf, but I don't know how to print to pdf the `Conclusiony` which is a renderText. And how does it work for renderPlot and renderUi? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reactive conductor for `Conclusiony`:

```
Conclusiony <- reactive({
    
    if(input$primavar==1 | input$primavar==2){
      if(testey()$p.value < 0.05){mensaje="We reject the null hypothesis, the variable is stationary"}else{mensaje="We keep the null hypothesis, the variable is not stationary"}
      mensaje}
    else {
      if(testey()$p.value > 0.05){mensaje="We accept the null hypothesis, the variable is stationary"}else{mensaje="We reject the null hypothesis, the  variable is not stationary"}
      mensaje}
  })

output$Conclusiony <- renderText({
  Conclusiony()
})
```